# bugfixing while developing with git

Tags: git, workflow

I'm wondering if anybody could give advice on the best way to approach development & bug fixing while using git. My company recently moved over to github to keep a centralized repo.
We normally have a master branch that is what we have in the production site.
Then we have a development branch that we use to keep the future updates to the master branch, and each coder has it's own set of branches (honestly, the set is not larger than 1 normally) that get merged into development once the changes have been approved.

Thing is, besides development I do have to do some bug fixing every once in a a while.

As usually my working branch is rather dirty, with a lot of modified files, I keep a separated copy of the repository that is always in the development branch, so I don't have to worry about changing stashing/changing branches when bug fixing, but I was wondering if any of you have an advice on how to approach this?

Basically, the only way I found to do it is to stash my changes and then change the branch, but I don't like that.

I've checked several of the suggestions SO gives when typing this, and not one was even close.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd use the same approach you are - keep a second repository.  Bug fixes should then be done on a bug-specific branch (from the appropriate source branch) in that repository.  The problem with using stash etc. to continue on the current branch is that it is intrusive.  I also find it can leave some tools a bit confused if their dependency tracking isn't perfect although often that indicates other issues.  Just an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't think that having a lot of modified files around is a good thing. I prefer a lot of smaller commits, although sometimes I get all excited about a problem that I forget to commit stuff (but thats more for larger features).

In those cases, I'd stash and switch branches. If that's not an option due to the size or kind of modified data, you can also create a temporary storage branch and do a commit just checking in everything currently being around there. You can undo that commit with `git reset` when you return and re-checkout the original branch (or just do the very same thing on the branch you've been working on). This allows (in contrast to a stash) to also check in files which are not yet in the index. Think of it as an extended stash.

The advantage of a temporary storage branch is that you can push that to a remote too, e.g. to continue work on another device (I use that to sync dirty working trees between devices if I have to abort development and going to continue on another device).

[git-flow](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/) is a nice helper to maintain a clean branching workflow for bugfix branches etc.. I don't think it follows the proposal above though.

On the other hand, it should be noted that having a clean repository for bughunting (if the source of the bug isn't obvious) can be helpful. Sometimes, subtle changes have crept in compared to the version the reporting user has.